# In Fermat's last theorem, is there any way to solve it using LTE when n is 3?

Tags: number-theory

In Fermat's last theorem, is there any way to solve it using LTE(lifting the exponent) Lemma when n is 3?

Comment: What is lifting the exponent?

Comment: @D_S https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lifting_The_Exponent_Lemma

Comment: @백영진: did you cite some article (from arxiv) (without mentioning this) and/or are you the author of that article? If you're citing then please update your comment with mentioning this - to converge to academic conventions... (updating a comment is not possible, but it is possible to copy&paste it to a new one, edit it, and delete the old one)

Comment: In an older essay http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups.pdf (still in draft-mode, sorry) I discuss the problem of the FLT a bit in connection with LTE on pages 34-35. Unfortunately, when I wrote my first version I never heard of the term "LTE" and have thus my own notation and style, so you likely need to read the introducing chapters, too.